# How do I remove leading tabs/spaces from my character vector?

Tags: r

I have this character vector:

```
[1] "　　　　　　USD(WorldTotal)"       "　　　　　　JPY(WorldTotal)"      
[3] "　　　　　　EURO(WorldTotal)"      "　　　　　　KRW(WorldTotal)"      
[5] "　　　　　　OTHER(WorldTotal)"     "　　　　　　　　　RUB(WorldTotal)"
```

and am trying to remove spaces from the vector.

I tried multiple ways to do this,

```
currency = trimws(currency)
currency = gsub("[[:blank:]]", "", currency)
```

none of which worked. I don't understand how this is the case. Could someone explain for me?

```
data = structure(list(currency = c("      USD (World Total)"      , 
NA, "      JPY (World Total)"      , NA, "      EURO (World Total)"      
), Types = c("Amounts(millionUSD)", "Share(%) (%)", "Amounts(millionUSD)", 
"Share(%) (%)", "Amounts(millionUSD)")), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

the variable in question is `currency'.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example using `dput`. Here your example is working well.

Comment: sorry! edited now

Comment: Currency is a column in the "data" data frame.  The syntax is `data$currency<-trimws(data$currency)`

Comment: @DaveT: ah no I attached the dataset. I didn't have any error messages. It's just simply that the function didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
data$currency <- trimws(data$currency, whitespace = "[\\h\\v\\t ]")
```

Comment: Beware that this won’t work in R 3.5, only in R 3.6: `trimws` has no `whitespace` argument before that.

Comment: I couldn't make this work either. I just edited my question to give a reproducible example.

Comment: can you try now, if I understood correctly it should work